# Why doesn't this limit exist? $\displaystyle\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sin^2 a}{(1-\cos a)^2}$

Tags: limits

Why doesn't this limit exist?

> $$\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sin^2 a}{(1-\cos a)^2}$$

Comment: The limit as $a\to 0$? $a\to\infty$? Something else?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax or Latex to present your question in a readable form. In addition, please specify the point of the limit, or else the question does not make sense.

Comment: You´re welcome!

Comment: a goes to infinity,thanks

Comment: If it existed, what would its value be, in your opinion ?

Comment: If it helps, this can be reduced to $1/\tan^2(a/2)$.

Comment: Becaues it's periodic and not constant.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Search for two different sequences $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ going to $+\infty$ such that
$$
\exists\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\sin^2a_n}{(1-\cos a_n)^2}=:a
$$
and
$$
\exists\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\sin^2b_n}{(1-\cos b_n)^2}=:b
$$
with $a\neq b$.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the graph, we see that for any $t>0$, we can find a sequence $a_n$ such that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin^2 a_n}{(1-\cos a_n)^2} = t$$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If a limit $a\to a_0$ exists than we need to guarantee that any sequence $a_n$ with $a_n \to a$ for $n \to \infty$ gives the same result. Investigate the two sequences $a_n = \frac{\pi}{2} n $ and $a_n = \pi n$. Note, that both expressions go to $\infty$ for $n \to \infty$.